# ridgeline histograms different colours

Tags: python, joypy

I am trying to create a ridgeline plot and I want every one of the subplots to have a different colour. Initially, I achieved this with this command:

```
import joypy
import numpy as np

fig, axes = joypy.joyplot(log_df, color=["k","b","r","g"])"
```

Resulting plot:

[image: Resulting plot]

However, this resulted in a plot that wasn't a histogram. I want to create histograms. Thus, I used this:

```
fig, axes = joypy.joyplot(log_df, fill= True, hist= True, bins=128, overlap = 0, color=["k","b","r","g"])
```

I, then, got this error message:

> The 'color' keyword argument must have one color per dataset, but 1 datasets and 4 colors were provided

I hadn't got this message before. I only get it with the histogram. Do you have any idea how I can create histograms that have the different colours that I want?

I was trying to get subplots of different colours, but it doesn't work when my plots are histograms.

Comment: Total guess based on your error message: color=["k","b","r","g"] should be color=[["k"],["b"],["r"],["g"]]

Comment: Hello. I just tried what you said and I get the error message: "ValueError: RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4"

Comment: OK, color=[[0,0,0],[0,0,255],[255,0,0],[0,255,0]] .

Comment: Again, I get "ValueError: The 'color' keyword argument must have one color per dataset, but 1 datasets and 4 colors were provided".

Comment: I can't see your code at this point but this page does demonstrate how to do it. Look at "Different color for each goup." 
https://python-charts.com/distribution/ridgeline-plot-matplotlib/